# regular expression to remove original message from reply mail using in java?

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-mail

In my forum, users can reply through email. I am handling mails from their reply. When they are replying the original message getting appended. I want to get only the reply message not the original message.

I have to write regular expression for gmail & hotmail.

I **written regex for gmail** as follows :

```
\n.*wrote:(?s).*--End of Post--
```

It is removing the original message except date.
I want to remove the date also.

**before removing the original message :**

```
 hi 33

 On Tue, May 11, 2010 at 4:18 PM, Mmmmm, Rrrrr
 <Rrrr.Mmmmm@uuuuu.com>wrote:

  The following update has been posted to this discussion:
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  test as user 222
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [$MESSAGE_SIGNATURE_HEADER$]



  --End of Post--
```

**When I use the above regex it is filtering as follows :**

```
 hi 33

 On Tue, May 11, 2010 at 4:18 PM, Mmmmm, Rrrrr
```

Here i want only the actual message 'hi 33' not that date. How can I filter the date      using above regex?

Also **I need regex for Hotmail** also.

I appreciate for any reply.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (this will match everything that should be removed):

```
On\s+\w+,\s+\w+\s+\d+,\s+\d+\s+at\s+\d+:\d+\s+\w+,.*?wrote:.*?--End of Post--
```

Or the simpler version:

```
On.*?wrote:.*?--End of Post--
```

Comment: Maybe the reason it works in one but not the other is because in the "application" you are not setting the dot (.) to also match the newline "\n". You have to do this to make it work.

Comment: How to ignore the new lines ? Could u modify that expression and tell me ?

Comment: Try adding `(?s)` to the start of the regex to set singleline mode.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. **To skip new lines** i modified in this way ....

On\s+\w+,\s+\w+\s+\d+,\s+\d+\s+at\s+\d+:\d+\s+\w+,\s+\w+,\s+\w+(?s).*?wrote:.*\n(?s).*--End of Post--